# How do I calculate the percentage of a number?

Tags: php, percentage

I would like to calculate, in PHP, the percentage of a number. For example:

```
$percentage = 50;
$totalWidth = 350;
```

For this example, 50% of 350 = 175

How can I do that?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

```
$percentage = 50;
$totalWidth = 350;

$new_width = ($percentage / 100) * $totalWidth;
```

Comment: No one cares about $totalWidth = 0... Why?

Comment: @GeorgyLiparteliani because any percentage of zero is zero. The variable $totalWidth isn't the dividend, is a multiplicator.

Comment: 50% of 350 = 175 I would do it that way, it's more logical for me: `($totalWidth*$percentage)/100` it is the same, but I like it more.

Comment: There's no need for parentheses. Multiplication and division have the same priority and therefore `$new_width = $percentage / 100 * $totalWidth;` it's the same

Comment: Simple and concise. I prefer the parenthesis, whether they are needed by the rules of precedence or not. It makes order clear, and readable.

Answer (score 27):

Divide `$percentage` by 100 and multiply to `$totalWidth`. Simple maths.

Comment: in case the type is an integer it is better if you multiply first, then divide by 100. Example when dividing first: int answer = 50/100 = 0.5 (int rounds 0.5 to 1); answer*width = 1*350 = 350. D'oh.

Comment: @Ozzy Types don't matter here. If a calculation results in a fraction, the result will automatically be a float and won't be rounded.